# Select row of data if next row contains zero

Tags: list-manipulation

I am a new user of Mathematica, and just faced a problem. 
I have a data set of three columns, and want to select only those rows that go before the rows, which contain 0 in the third column. 
Eventually I want to create a new data set containing only these selected rows.

Can it be performed in Mathematica?
Thank you in advance!

(edited)

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) to define a pattern of two elements, the second of which has a 0 in the second column.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {8, 4}, {5, 0}, {3, 2}, {8, 9}, {7, 0}, {2, 3}};

SequenceCases[data, {a_, {___, 0}} :> a]
(* {{8, 4}, {8, 9}} *)
```

Here `{a_, {___, 0}}` is the pattern for two rows, and the `:> a` says that we want to extract the first part of the pattern.

Comment: Great solution! There's no need to name `b`, you can use the pattern `{a_, {_, 0}}` or even `{a_, {___, 0}}` (to be more flexible, see @kglr's comment below other solution).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html):

```
data = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 8, 4}, {3, 5, 0}, {4, 3, 2}, {5, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 0}, {7, 2, 3}};
ReplaceList[data, {___, a_, {__, 0}, ___} :> a]
```

> {{2, 8, 4}, {5, 8, 9}}

Or combinations of

[`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) and [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html):

```
Extract[data, Position[data[[2 ;;, -1]], 0]]
```

> {{2, 8, 4}, {5, 8, 9}}

[`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) and [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
data[[PositionIndex[data[[2 ;;, -1]]][0]]]
```

> {{2, 8, 4}, {5, 8, 9}}

Comment: Thank you a lot!! It works perfectly for my data set. I wonder now how the command Extract would work for 3 columns (zero value is in the 3rd column)?

Comment: @Anna, made a small change  ( replaced `{_,0}` with `{__,0}`) so that all methods should work for any number of columns (as long as the criterion is "the last column is of the next row is 0")

Comment: @ChristopherLamb, thank you; it is fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

```
data //Pick[Most@#, #[[2;;,3]],0]&
```

> {{2, 8, 4}, {5, 8, 9}}

Comment: This is much faster than other methods posted for large input. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we are interested in every row *exactly* preceding a row whose last entry (column) is equal to zero then it is possible to use [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and its *undocumented* last argument.

In short, the last argument of `Partition` allows to apply a user defined function to every n-tuple of elements generated; eg. evaluating `Partition[{1,2,3},2,1,{1,-1},Null]` produces

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}

while using the last argument and evaluating , `Partition[{1,2,3},2,1,{1,-1},Null,f]` produces

> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3]}

where `f` can be any user-defined (or built-in, for that matter) function of an appropriate number of arguments.

Returning to the question, assuming `data` is a list of lists of three elements, then evaluating

```
Partition[data, 2, 1, {1, -1}, Null, If[#2[[-1]] == 0&&#1[[-1]] != 0, #1, Nothing] &]
```

should return the desired result.

> ```
> {{-3,2,2},{1,2,2},{3,0,-3},{-2,-3,-2},{-2,1,-2},{2,3,2},
>     {2,-1,2},{2,3,1},{2,3,-3},{0,1,2},{2,0,-3},{2,-3,-3}}
> ```

Please note how the second and third arguments to `Partition` instruct it to create pairs (2) of elements from the initial list that differ by one entry (1) while the fourth and fifth arguments are used to instruct `Partition` where in the new lists it should place the first and last element of the list and what to use for padding new lists, if needed (More details and examples are available at the documentation page for `Partition`).

---

Here are the example `data` used

```
BlockRandom[
  data = RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{-3, 3}], {100, 3}];
  RandomSeeding -> 123456789]
```

Comment: I used this feature in  [these q/a s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a125%20Partition%20undocumented). Btw, you can also use `BlockMap[ If[#[[2,-1]] == 0&&#[[1,-1]] != 0, #[[1]], Nothing] &,data,2,1];`  (+1)

Comment: @kglr indeed it is the case that I learned about this feature from one of your answers; thanks for pointing out [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 8, 4}, {3, 5, 0}, {4, 3, 2}, {5, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 0}, {7, 2, 3}};

sel[{_, x_}] /; FreeQ[x, 0] := Nothing
sel[{x_, _}] := x

BlockMap[sel, data, 2, 1]
```

{{2, 8, 4}, {5, 8, 9}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {8, 4}, {5, 0}, {3, 2}, {8, 9}, {7, 0}, {2, 3}};

With[{data = data}, Block[{list, prevSublist}, 
list = data;
prevSublist = {};
Reap[Do[
If[MemberQ[sublist, 0] && Length[prevSublist] != 0, 
Sow[prevSublist]];
prevSublist = sublist, {sublist, list}]][[2, 1]]]]

(*{{8, 4}, {8, 9}}*)
```